# How do I write on top of a background image with bootstrap 3.3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, scroll, background

I need a "background text" like this > ([EXAMPLE](http://attafothman.olympe.in/))

The text doesn't go up when I scroll down the page.

my .css for background image

```
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/image-bg-jpg.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
  webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were you i would put the image in with an image tag, then position it fixed, like this:
`<img class="img" />
    .img{ min-width: 100%; min-  height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 0; }`

And then put your text in a div under it like:

```
<div class="div">text goes here</div>
.div{ margin-top: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in that example is in a container with fixed positioning:

```
.jumbotron .container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

<div class="container"></div>
```

You should acquaint yourself with the browser's document inspector to discover this type of thing.